# Namensgebungsregelung für deutsche Bundesländer

Tags: etymology, morphology

Deutschland hat 16 Bundesländer. Es gibt davon welche, die einen Namen haben, der aus einem Wort besteht (z.B. Bayern, Berlin, Brandenburg).
Dann gibt es wiederum Bundesländer, die zusammengesetzte Namen haben (z.B. Baden-Württemberg, Sachsen-Anhalt, Schleswig-Holstein).

Bei Baden-Württemberg steht auf der [Wikipedia-Seite](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg):

> Er wurde 1952 durch Zusammenschluss der Länder Württemberg-Baden, Baden und Württemberg-Hohenzollern gegründet.

Demzufolge schließe ich daraus, dass zur Namengebung Baden und Württemberg herangezogen wurden, weil diese am häufigsten vorkommen, und zusammengesetzt werden.

Bei Mecklenburg-Vorpommern findet sich bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecklenburg-Vorpommern) zum Namensursprung folgendes:

> Die Geschichte von Mecklenburg-Vorpommern als politische Einheit beginnt 1945 durch die Vereinigung des Landes Mecklenburg (die historischen Landesteile Mecklenburg-Schwerin und Mecklenburg-Strelitz) mit dem bei Deutschland verbliebenen Teil Vorpommerns (ohne Stettin).

Daraus schließe ich, dass sich der Name einfach aus den beiden Ländern Mecklenburg und Vorpommern zusammensetzt.

Daher kommt nun meine Frage: Gibt es irgendwo allgemein definierte Regeln zur Namenszusammensetzung der Bundesländer?
Angenommen, die Länder Sachsen und Sachsen-Anhalt würden sich zusammenschließen, wie müsste / könnte da der Bundesland-Name heißen? Wären solche Varianten wie Sachsen-Sachsen-Anhalt, Sachsen-Sachsen oder Groß-Sachsen möglich?

Comment: Wenn überhaupt scheint mir das eine Gesetzesfrage zu sein. Ansonsten gibt es keine Regeln der Deutschen Sprache, wie man etwas nennen darf. Neu-Sachsen, Super-Sachsen oder Das-Land-im-Osten wären alles mögliche Namen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the German language.

Comment: Wie der Name eines Landes zustande kam, lässt sich durch historische Untersuchung beantworten. Die Namensfindung für ein neues Land wäre ein politischer Prozess. Der Name wäre dann vermutlich deutsch, aber nicht durch die Regeln der deutschen Sprache determiniert. Eine Anmerkung zu Baden-Württemberg: das war keine heuristische Entscheidung. Vielmehr bestanden die Länder Württ. und Baden schon vor der Gründung des Deutschen Kaiserreiches als souveräne Staaten. Württ.-Bad. enstand erst nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg durch die Teilung Badens, der Zusatz *-Hohenzollern* diente v.a. der Unterscheidung.